# How to get the gross weight of similar and dissimilar items ordered by customers using kotlin firestore & for loop/iterating over map collections

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an ecommerce application and for admin app, I need to calculate the gross weight of items orders by customers so that I can place the purchase order of how much stock with my supplier.I failed to implement the best method to achieve this and I am having to use map filtering by using each key i.e Banana, Mango individually

the method I used works though but you know for thousands of items of my ecommerce store, I can't add the name of each item manually to for loop of firestore reference and map collection to calculate the gross weight of goods.
I know the method I used is not the right way to get the sum of weights of items present in orders placed by customers.
I am eagerly seeking someone's help to solve this problem and let me know how to run the for loop, forEach loop, nested Loop or whatever, howevera as well as map iteration to get the gross weight of items(both similar and dissimilar) present in firestore database.

Here is my code:

```
db.collection("orders").document(formattedNumber).collection("myorders").get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot -

    for (i in querySnapshot.documents) {

        val iMap = i["itemsmap"] as Map<String, Int>

        val banana = iMap.filter { (key) -> key == "Banana" }
        val strawberry = iMap.filter { (key) -> key == "Strawberry" }
        val mango = iMap.filter { (key) -> key == "Mango" }

        grossweightBanana += banana.map { it.value }.sum()
        grossweightStrawberry += strawberry.map { it.value }.sum()
        grossweightMango += mango.map { it.value }.sum()

        grossweightMap["Banana"] = grossweightBanana
        grossweightMap["Strawberry"] =  grossweightStrawberry
        grossweightMap["Mango"] = grossweightMango

        db.collection("GrossWeight").document("GrossWeight").update("GrossWeight", grossweightMap).addOnCompleteListener {
            requireActivity().showToast("gross weights of items ordered by customers have been saved to your database.")
            


        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand one thing. You seem to assume that `iMap` contains multiple items per a single key, e.g. multiple items with `key==banana`. Is it some kind of a multi map or something?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot, and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Exactly, you got me right. I have thousands of maps with <itemname, weights> and I have to sum up the values of all matching/non matching items and generate an final map for admin so that he/she can know how much stock we need to place order with our supplier. thousands of customers placed ordered of bananas, mangoes, cherries and we have to get the gross weight of all items present in thousands of maps. every single order contains a map of <items,quantities>

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this kind of problems with group and reduce/fold like this:

```
val grossweightMap = maps
    .flatMap { it.entries }
    .groupingBy { it.key }
    .fold(0) { acc, item -> acc + item.value }
```

Where `maps` is of `List<Map<String, Int>>` type.

I'm not sure how to adjust this to your example, because it is not fully clear for me. It seems you need to find gross weights from all maps, but you perform db updates for each map separately, in the middle of calculating the weight (?). I guess it will be something along lines:

```
val grossweightMap = querySnapshot.documents
    .flatMap { (it["itemsmap"] as Map<String, Int>).entries }
    .groupingBy { it.key }
    .fold(0) { acc, item -> acc + item.value }

db.collection("GrossWeight").document("GrossWeight").update("GrossWeight", grossweightMap)
```

Comment: The piece of code you told is rather close to the problem but it just printing the <key,value> pairs of each map but not adding the weight/quantities of items present in maps. 
val mapA = mutalbleMapOf("mango" to 5KG, "banana" to 24 units, "cherry" to 2KG, "guava" to 4KG)
val mapB = mutalbleMapOf("mango" to 8KG, "banana" to 36 units, "cherry" to 5KG)

Comment: It adds weights, but probably not in the way you expected. As I said, your example is a little confusing, because you filter the map for items with `key=banana` and sum them even if there is probably only one item like that. But I admit I didn't notice that you iterate over multiple maps. So is this your case? Iterate over multiple maps and sum values per each key in any map?

Comment: And if you have a list of maps and you need to process them all to find weights then why you perform db updates in each loop iteration?

Comment: The piece of code you told is rather close to the problem but it just printing the <key,value> pairs of each map.
The problem:
val mapA = mutableMapOf("mango" to 5KG, "banana" to 24 units, "guava" to 4KG)
val mapB = mutableMapOf("mango" to 8KG, "banana" to 36 units, "cherry" to 5KG)

val mapGrossWeight = mutableMapOf("mango" to 13kg, "banana" to 60 units, "guava to 4kg, "cherry" to 5KG)

Now I want to add the weights of matching/non-matching items present in thousands of maps and generate a third map of <items/weights> as mapGrossWeight so that I can place bulk order with my supplier.

Comment: Perfect!!! you made my day, God bless you. This just solved my problem and it is working perfectly and calculating the sum of all quantities both matching/non matching in multiple maps.
val grossweightMap = querySnapshot.documents
    .flatMap { (it["itemsmap"] as Map<String, Int>).entries }
    .groupingBy { it.key }
    .fold(0) { acc, item -> acc + item.value }

db.collection("GrossWeight").document("GrossWeight").update("GrossWeight", grossweightMap)